# Run unit tests with testthat without package

Tags: r, testing, shiny, testthat

I have a shiny application which uses like 4 functions. I would like to test these functions but it's not a package. How am i supposed to structure my code ? and execute these tests without devtools ?

Comment: why without `devtools`?

Comment: @drmariod : i can't use it in my R project and don't know why and how to configure it without creating a package ...

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can execute tests with `testthat::test_dir()` or `testthat::test_file()`. Neither relies on the code being in a package, or using devtools, just the [testthat](https://github.com/hadley/testthat) package.

There are few requirements on how to structure your code.
If it were me, I would create a `tests` directory and add my test scripts under there, which would look something like:

```
|- my_shiny_app
|  |- app.R
|  |- tests
|     |- test_foo.R
|     |- test_bar.R
```

Then you can run your tests with `test_dir('tests')`, assuming you're in the `my_shiny_app` directory.

Your test scripts will have they same [structure they have for packages](https://r-pkgs.org/testing-basics.html#sec-tests-mechanics-workflow) but you'd replace the `library()` call with `source()` referencing the file where your functions are defined.

Comment: The above link is broken, but I think the new link is likely [Test Mechanics and Workflow](https://r-pkgs.org/testing-basics.html#sec-tests-mechanics-workflow).

Answer (score 1):

If you have few functions without a package structure, it is better to write single test files manually (so with some simple if/error catching system) that you call with `Rscript test_file1.R`.

If you start to use the package format instead (which would be advisable for further 'safe' developing) and you still do not want to use `testthat`, I advise you to follow this blog post: [here](http://www.mdlerch.com/writing-tests-for-r-packages-without-testthat-and-runit.html)